# Extracting a URL from a list of flash variables from bash

Tags: bash, html-parsing

I would want to download the ( .smil ) file  with bash

The link of the file looks like that

```
http://website.fr:1535/3PBOLaEQ2kC19nmxtIYg8a4ziKlPQ9l0Jkn2hecxIexEZYc32znTlugcyxus%3D-08Fw3XtDFE9wrMbCGOZTOw%3D%3D.mp4?audioindex=0.smil
```

The filename -- everything after the last `/` and before the `.mp4` -- changes on each reload, and is embedded in the site's code, within the `flashvars` parameter:

```
<param name="flashvars" value="netstreambasepath=http%3A%2F%2Fwebsite.fr%2Fvideo%2Fcelestial_method%2F5675-episode-4-04-fragments-d-emotions&id=yui_3_17_2_13_1414622045495_169&image=http%3A%2F%2Fi.jpg&skin=%2Fcomponents%2Fcom_vodvideo%2Fmediaplayer%2Fskin%2Fadn%2Fadn.xml&bufferlength=16000&repeat=list&title=undefined&logo=undefined&plugins=http%3A%2F%2Fwebsite.fr%2Fcomponents%2Fcom_vodvideo%2Fmediaplayer%2Fplugins%2Fcontrol%2Fcontrol.swf%2Chttp%3A%2F%2...wJgu2BiCfbqlqd6sQDZUlMO56C270iwoWT7GZ6txc%253D-ep69DPqWGsFsiQgVBAbiHQ%253D%253D.mp4%3Faudioindex%3D0.smil%22%2C%22default%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%website.fr%3A1935%2FS2v5wo0p7Fum7GI8_WlyBJU%252BXtVRjXY%252BkTuo_TXa0Wv0tpLLzR37DWx0AQkK52G9FMwJgu2BiCfbqlqd6sQDZUlMO56C270iwoWT7GZ6txc%253D-ep69DPqWGsFsiQgVBAbiHQ%253D%253D.mp4%3Faudioindex%3D0.smil%22%7D%5D&control.pluginmode=FLASH&mulutibu_v4_3.back=false&mulutibu_v4_3.cc=true&mulutibu_v4_3.pluginmode=FLASH&controlbar.position=over&dock.position=true">
```

How can I extract the link to launch VLC with the file directly?

Comment: What is the question here? How to download a file? (Use `wget` or `curl`.) How to find that link name? (No idea.)

Comment: Hello I want to download the link generated by the site but I wonder how because this link changes every viewing of the video ( rtmp ) I want to get back the link of the video and to download her with Bash

Comment: If the link changes then you are going to need to scrape the link off of the site with some tool.

Comment: This sounds more like a situation where you need something (ie. a scraper) developed for you than a place where you're developing a piece of software yourself and asking for help with a specific technical problem. The latter is a better fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: I know well but I would want to get this link without  user manipulation

Comment: ...another thing to consider, by the way, is that bash might not be the best tool for your job. Looking at the content you're trying to extract, both a urldecoding library call and a HTML parser would be very helpful; Python has the former built-in and the latter readily available, bash, not so much (without installing third-party software).

Comment: I want to develop a script I look for examples to be guided in the creation of the script I have not begun yet

Comment: The python would be a good idea but I begin and I have never created script have you examples?

Comment: The error you received means exactly what it says -- your site has bad HTML, and xmllint can't parse it. You'll probably need to use something like `lxml.html` instead.

Comment: hello I know not this option you can explain to me I look on Web and it is an option for python.?

Answer (score 1):

The following would be a place to start:

```
# credit to https://gist.github.com/cdown/1163649
urldecode() {
    local url_encoded="${1//+/ }"
    printf '%b' "${url_encoded//%/\x}"
}

flashvars_u=$(
  curl http://your-website/ | \
    xmllint --html --xmlout - | \
    xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//param[@name="flashvars"]' -v @value
)
flashvars=$(urldecode "$flashvars")
```

Further extracting content from `flashvars` is hindered by the content being provided only in redacted/modified form, making it impossible to test whether code is correct.

Comment: i have an error  File "test.py", line 3
    urldecode() {
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @ben36, this is shell, not python.

Comment: I have test and I believe that I could work but have a problem I forgot that I must be connected to the site